# SAS how to convert data set to formatted XML file output

Tags: xml, sas

I try to export my dataset as XML file.

I wrote the code

```
libname xml_file xml "S:\Applicant.xml"  XMLTYPE=ORACLE;
data xml_file.Applicant;
    set Applicant;
run;
```

then output is

[image]

However, the format I have to submit is below

[image]

I noticed the slightly different.

Question 1 is how can I code sas as -- applicant university="my university code"--
like below

AND everything goes into inside of --applicant--

[image]

Q2

Comment: We cannot code from photographs of text.  Please paste the example data as a data step and the desired XML as text.

Comment: Did you read the documentation on using a MAP file for exporting to XML?  https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/engxml/p0vpwjxebljiaqn1itlkt12rwefk.htm